# Jsoup set Accept-Language

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

Is there any possibility to set for the Jsoup connection the Accept-Language parameter.
I've tried with:

```
Jsoup.connection(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0").get();
Jsoup.connection(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").get();
```

but doesn't work...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add the `Header` to the `Connection` like mentioned below

```
Jsoup.connection(url)
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0")
        .header("Accept-Language", "en")
        .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate,sdch");//can add as many as you like
        .get();
```