# Set JSoup to connect only in english pages - How to?

Tags: connection, httprequest, jsoup, user-agent

I've tryed this solution here [Jsoup set Accept-Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334960/jsoup-set-accept-language) to make my JSoup connection only accept pages that come in english. Unfortunately it didn't work and my output was still:

[image]

I don't know if this happened because when the user agent says `("Accept-Language", "en")` is to rather take english pages version instead of other languages or really for just accept the english ones. Anyway, the question speaks for itself, if there is a way to, how may I set the JSoup connection to only accept english pages?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your problem correctly. I set it by adding .header("Accept-Language", "en") at the end of Jsoup connect and it worked for me. this is mine:  org.jsoup.Connection con = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl)
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
     .header("Accept-Language", "en");

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to write a language check method

```
public String languageCheck(String page){
String result = ""
   List<String> pagesArray= new ArrayList<String>();
   pagesArray.add(page);

   if(pagesArray.get(0)!=null){
   char []test  = pagesArray.get(0).trim().toCharArray();
       if(Character.isLetter(test[0]))
        {
            System.out.println("ok");
                       result = "okay"
        }else{
            System.out.println("Nok");
                       result = "Not Okay"
        }
   }

return result;

}
```

use this method to remove non English pages, hope it helps you